# Binding Directive Scope Value to HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an AngularJS directive. This directive has some custom attributes. I will be using the directive like this:

```
<my-directive show-links="false" />
```

`show-links` is an attribute that I want to default to `true` if a developer does not specifically set it. In an attempt to build this directive, I have the following JavaScript:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      showLinks: '=?'
    },
    templateUrl: '/directives/my-directive.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      if (angular.isUndefined($scope.showLinks)) {
        $scope.showLinks = true;
        console.log('show links? ' + $scope.showLinks);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

My HTML in my-directive.html looks like the following:

```
<div><h1>Hello! {{showLinks}}</h1></div>
<div ng-if="showLinks == true"">
  <a href='#'>do something</a>
</div>
```

When this directive is evaluated, I can see in the console window "show links? true". However, on the screen, I do not see "true" printed beside the word "Hello". Its like the HTML is getting rendered before showLinks is in scope. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use `compile` instead of `link`. It's used in a different phase.

Answer (score 0):

I remember having issues with isolate scope - solution was to add anything that was in the isolate scope object into the directive HTML code itself, like so:

```
.directive('widgetRecentEntries', function(){
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                recents: "=recents"
            },
            templateUrl: "ngapp/js/tpl/widget-recent-entries.html"
        };
    })
```

The directive HTML/template:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal flip-in" ng-repeat="item in recents" recents="recents">
    <dt>
    <a href="/{{item.seo_name}}.html">
        <img src="{{item.logo_url}}" alt="" width="80">
    </a>
</dt>
<dd>
    <p><a href="/{{item.seo_name}}.html">{{item.name}}</a></p> 
</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: If I do not use scope: `{ showLinks: '=?' }`, I get a run time error.

Comment: @user70192 Try putting it like this (your directive HTML code):
`<div ng-if="showLinks == true"" showLinks="showLinks">
  <a href='#'>do something</a>
</div>`
Also note that you have 2x closing double-quotes after `showLinks == true` (may not have any influence but still...) AND also use `===` instead of `==` when comparing against boolean values

Comment: Ignoring the syntax of ng-if... I would think that true or false would be displayed beside the word "Hello!" in the directive I showed above. However, nothing is getting shown.